# How to translate 就 into English as in 这就是个很好的例子?

Tags: translation

> 这**就**是个很好的例子。

Either with or without 就, it can be translated to

> This is a good example.

Comment: This is a good example. vs. THIS is a good example. (maybe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 就 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/808/

就 has many usages,  I would say "definitely" is applicable here:

这是个很好的例子 - This is a very good example

这(就)是个很好的例子 - This (definitely) is a very good example

是他偷了我的钱 - He is the one who stole my money

(就)是他偷了我的钱 - He (definitely) is the one who stole my money

'就' (definitely) here is for emphasis function. Without it, the sentence's meaning doesn't change much, but with it, the emphasis on the object and the tone of seriousness would increase.

*就是他 - you sure it is him*

*是他 -  you say it is him*

Since it is for emphasis, you can use 'exactly' or 'actually instead of 'definitely' in English

Answer (score 2):

> This, exactly, is a good example.

or

> This, out of a thousand any of others, is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

这就是个很好的例子 is probably like *This demonstrates a very good example.* It's not a word-for-word translation though.

这就是个很好的例子 is saying "If you want to find a good example, here is a one."

Answer (score 0):

就： Original meaning 本义: Meaning (orig) to move to a high place (now) meaning just.

Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:
Compound 就 from building-jing 京 jīng and phonetic injured-hand-you 尤 yóu.

Maybe that is the sense in 就业: get a job (on the notion of: a job is better than no job, a step up?)

这是个很好的例子。
This is a good example.
这就是个很好的例子。
This really is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post ["unified theory of 就](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/a-unified-theory-of-%E5%B0%B1-meaning)" read it.

My answer: 就 is "AND" , thus your sentence must be translated as

> "**And** this is a good exapmle".

Now, what does this mean? Well, what does adding "and" in this position mean in English? Hard to say, yes? The same in Chinese case. Natives struggle to explain what 就 does.