# What exactly does 就 mean in combination with other words?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Recently I came across 铺就, today I have 造就。I tend to think of 就 as 'then'. Maybe that is wrong.

What did 就 originally mean? It seems to show a building and an injured hand??

There are other words with *就。
成就，将就，迁就，牵就 even 可就

How should I understand 就 in these combinations? What is its role?

Answer (score 1):

[就](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/xs/5C31.htm) has the meaning of 完成;成功 (accomplish) in [造就](http://www.zdic.net/c/0/14f/331540.htm) (bring up / achievements) and [成就](http://www.zdic.net/c/0/13e/306996.htm) (achieve;accomplish).

> (9) 完成;成功 [accomplish]
>
> (10) 又如:就亲(成就婚事,成亲);就名(成就功名)

When in 将就, 迁就 it means *accommodate*.

> (12) 迁就;将就 [accommodate oneself to; suit; fit; yield]
>
> (13) 又如:半推半就;牵就;就着(就便;顺便);就滑(随便;方便)

The original meaning of [就](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/sw/5C31.htm) is

> 就，高也。从京从尤。尤，異於凡也。，籒文就。疾僦切 文二　重一

The left part 京 means *high; tall*, the right part 尤 means *special; out of the common*.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extended discussion about 就 here http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?7,138618,page=1

> My thinking is. 就 mainly means " then; just; only; near; close to

~

> The original meaning of 就
>
> http://www.shuowen.org/view/3315
>
> '就，高也。从京从尤。尤，異於凡也
>
> 京 = high
>
> 尤 = extraordinary
>
> 就 = high

~

> 廣韵曰。就、成也。迎也。卽也。皆其引伸之義也
>
> The core meaning of 就 is 'success; complete'; other means like 'get near' or 'then' are all extended from the original meaning

'就' in '铺就' and  '造就' are adverb for 'completed' because '铺' and '造' are verb.

铺 = to pave

铺就 = finish paving

~

造 = make

造就 = completed making = create

~

成就 (achievement) is a compound word

成= completed

就 = height;

成就 = achievement

~

将就，迁就 are also compound words

'就' in '将就'(put up with)  and  迁就 (accommodate) is a verb for 'approach' (you make accommodation to approach someone else's need or demand)

Answer (score 1):

- 就 as a standalone verb it used to mean "to take", but now it usually does not stand alone, but the meaning remains.
- 就 as a conjunction means "AND", thus extending original meaning "to take". Since you are "with an object" when you "take it", that is, it can be said that you are in a situation of "you AND it". Mind you there are many "and" in chinese (跟, 及, 也, 和, 并, 与, 而, 同 ect.) each has it's own connotation and perhaps evolved from a verb.

there is a disscussion about it, here [A unified theory of 就 meaning](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/a-unified-theory-of-%E5%B0%B1-meaning/21014#21014)

Comment: Great! Thanks, very interesting!