# Does 现在 make 就 redundant in "你现在就去做。"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm trying to find 就 used as "at once" in a sentence so that I can add it to my flashcards but the only sentence I've found like that would be "你现在就去做".
Issue is, 现在 already means "now" so that makes 就 redundant in the sentence doesn't it? Can anyone give me a proper sentence that uses 就 to mean "at once"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 就 in 你现在就去做 functions as the adverb "just".

你现在去做 = you go do it now

你现在(就)去做 = you (just) go do it now

> Example of 就 = at once; right away:

吃完飯去 = go after finish dinner

吃完飯(就)去 = go (right away) after finish dinner

*吃完飯 is the requirement. Once this requirement is met, then 去 occur at once*

完成工作付工資 = when you finished work, I will pay your service fee

完成工作(就)付工資 = when you finished work, I will pay your service fee (right away)

*完成工作 is the requirement . Once this requirement is met, then 付工資 occur at once*

Since 你现在就去做 doesn't include a requirement, 就 doesn't carry the meaning of 'at once; right away'

If it was 你等到明天就去做 (you go do it at once when tomorrow comes); 等到明天(wait till tomorrow arrives) would be the requirement.

Comment: ok fair enough, could you please give me a simple example sentence where 就 is used to mean "at once" or "right away"?

Comment: thank you! So then is "你刷牙就去睡觉" proper usage in this case?

Comment: You need to indicate the requirement is completed "你刷牙就去睡觉" could mean: "you go to sleep while brushing teeth" the correct format is "你刷完牙就去睡觉",  你刷了牙就去睡觉", " 你刷好牙就去睡觉"  or  "你刷牙之後就去睡觉"

Comment: thank you! I've learned much

Comment: "你刷牙就去睡觉" could also mean "You go to sleep whenever you brush your teeth" .  Similar to "我上课就睡覺" (I sleep whenever I attend school class)

Comment: I had never seen 完 before so I had to look up its usage, I see you listed "你刷完牙就去睡觉" and "你刷了牙就去睡觉" as proper usage, but from what I've just seen while researching 完 wouldn't it be more correct to say "你刷完牙了就去睡觉"?

Comment: '完' and '了'  in '刷完牙'  and '刷了牙' are both verb particle that indicate the verb is completed. you can combine 完 and 了 into '完了' as in "你刷(完了)牙就去睡觉"; but "你刷(完)牙(了)就去睡觉" is an incorrect form

Comment: But on the Chinese Grammar Wiki it says "If there is an object followed by the verb, 完 must be placed between the verb and the object. To indicate completion, 了 usually goes after the object." And gives "老板 开 完 会 了 。" as an example

Comment: Another function of. 了 is as a final particle--  to  indicate the sentence is completed. the only correct way to use "你刷完牙了" is to end the sentence there.

Comment: E.g. "你刷完牙了？好, 那就去睡吧." (you finished brushing teeth? Good, then you should go to sleep.)

Comment: thank you, that makes perfect sense

Comment: 老板开完会就去睡觉了 would be one sentence. and 了 is optional, it serves to indicate the sentence is completed, but we still can tell 老板开完会就去睡觉 is a  complete sentence without adding the final particle 了

Answer (score 0):

就 expresses *emergency* or *handling something quickly*  in Chinese. It's been used when something need to/must/want to be handled at certain point of time. E.g. 我现在就去; 我明天就上班; 我(现在)就来; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Language has built-in redundancy. I think that is in order to make sure the message gets across.

You might ask: When exactly is 'now'?

你现在就去做
Go and do it now, immediately!

In this case, I think 就 is emphatic: 你立刻去做。or 你立刻就去做。

就 is a [Pandora's box](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/a-unified-theory-of-%E5%B0%B1-meaning/21014#21014)!

> At once originally (early 13c.) meant "simultaneously," later "in one
> company" (c. 1300), and preserved the sense of "one" in the word; the
> phrase typically appeared as one word, atones; the modern meaning
> "immediately" is attested from 1530s.

'at once' would normally be translated as 赶快， 马上。

This sentence has 就：

天一下儿就冷了。
All at once the weather turned cold.

but 'at once' comes from ‘一下儿’