# What does 足有 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this in Matilda (p.13):

> 这本书的这一版本足有四百一十一页。
>   that edition contained four hundred and eleven pages.  [original English ([ref.](http://jssisdubai.com/document/uploaded/matilda.pdf))]
>   the book's [这本书的] edition [这一版本] has (?) [足有] 411 pages [四百一十一页].

The translation is direct, except for 足有 instead of just 有.  I've found other examples of 足有 online, e.g.:

> 等你回到家，你的收件箱足有一英尺厚。 [[YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B6%B3%E6%9C%89)]
>   When you come back, your inbox is a foot high.

I'm aware 足 is sometimes used to mean "enough": [足: why is "foot" also "enough"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/%e8%b6%b3-why-is-foot-also-enough)  So maybe 足 is used for emphasis in these sentences, but it'd be nice to clarify this.

**Question**: What does 足有 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「足」means *fully, entirely*.

> ...這一版本足有四百一十一頁
>
> ---
>
> *...this edition contains four hundred and eleven pages in its **entirety***
>
> or
>
> *...this edition contains **a full** four hundred and eleven pages*

The semantic relation is something like

> *sufficient/enough* (足夠) <> *full* <> *entire*

Answer (score 1):

*ABC* defines 足有 as:

> V.
>   (have/be) a full ...
>
> 他讲了足有两个钟头。
>   Tā jiǎngle zúyǒu liǎng ge zhōngtóu.
>   He lectured for a full two hours.

Answer (score 1):

足有 (fully have) has the same meaning as [足足](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/17030/): fully (e.g. one year, a hundred ounces)

足有四百一十一页 (fully have 411 pages)

足足有四百一十一页 (fully have 411 pages)

足足四百一十一页 (fully 411 pages)

All the above mean: "has 411 pages in its entirety"

Notice:

*足 in 足有 means "fully". It is different from the  足 in 足以, which  means "enough" . 
E.g. "要達到 1500c 才**足**以將铁熔化" (need to reach 1500c, to be **enough** to melt iron)*

The reason to use 足有(fully have) instead of just 有(have) is to emphasize the impressiveness of the number.

For example:

太阳**有**地球130万倍的体积 - The sun **has** the volumes of 1.3 million Earths  (a plain statement)

太阳**足有**地球130万倍的体积 - The sun **actually has** the volumes of 1.3 million Earths (stress the impressiveness of the number)

Answer (score 1):

It is just 足. There is no single word 足有, just 足 and 有 separately. It means "in full, wholly":

> 你的收件箱足有一英尺厚

"Your mailing trunk is fully / wholly possessed of all the thickness comprehended by one English foot."

To break it down:

> 你的 (your) + 收件箱 (mailing box / trunk) + 足 (fully or "is fully") + 有 (possessing) + 一 (one) + 英尺 (English foot, the unit of measure, 304.8 mm) + 厚 (thick, big, fat, plump, etc.).

So it's more for laying especial emphasis on the fact that the mailbox (or I presume, a synecdoche for the *stack of papers within*, as that seems to make more sense), is so big as named.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit like 'a mouthful of ...'